# Database tool for inter-db joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Can someone suggest a database tool?  I'm doing an enterprise integration, specifically selecting from both SQL Server and MySQL dbs.  I'd like to join tables in SQL Server with tables in MySQL for comparison and testing.  Portable if possible, I don't have Admin on the machines I'm running this on.  Thanks,

Comment: I do not think you can "join" tables from different DBMS, not even with a "database tool".

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Sure you can.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari you just need to set up "linked databases" and then query them across with a 4-part name, at least in SSMS. It can be done. It's just not "neat" or "clean".

Comment: How about MySQL Workbench? [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard-connection.html)

Comment: John, why don't you have "Admin" on the machines you're doing this on? If you need to _alter the SQL Server installation_ to support _the needs of the company_ then you're going to need some sort of administrative rights. Mostly you just need an SA level account on the server (or someone with those privs) and SSMS installed locally (assuming you can write the SQL queries yourself). If you need a graphical query builder across linked servers, that is outside my scope of knowledge.

Comment: To do so natively (from SQL Server anyway) you'd need a linked server to the MySQL server which, without admin on the machines, would be challenging.

Comment: To clarify, I'm working on (windows) server1.  The SQL Server is on server2, the MySQL db is on server3.  I don't have rights to install software on server1, so I can't install software.

Comment: I'll try the linked servers in MS.  That may do it.  Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. Linked servers is the name of the thing you want.

Comment: If you can't install software even on the machine you're working on you're going to be pretty hosed without an admin's help.

Comment: @John Creating a linked server requires sysadmin privileges in SQL Server.  If you don't have that you'll need to ask someone who does.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the MySQL side of things but you can do this with SSIS (SQL 2005+) or DTS (earlier than SQL 2005) as long as you have drivers that will connect to both instances.  You can write a package that will bring in datasets from both servers and store the results wherever (db, flat files, etc).

You could also write a powershell script to query the instances (assuming you have drivers/clients for both SQL Server and MySQL installed on your machine).

Comment: Ya no admin no linked dbs not an option.  Will try the Powershell.  Thanks